# What happened with “New ▸ Scala Script”?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I downloaded IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, created a new Scala project (tried both sbt and IDEA type) and now want to create a new Scala Script. I see New ▸ Scala Class, New ▸ Scala Worksheet, but not New ▸ Scala Script. Why? How?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just create a Scala class. It will create a Scala file and you will be able to use it as a script file.

Comment: Thank you, but I think I need the template. When I just created a file, sbt stumbled upon the bash commands, etc. When I tried to comment them out, bash stumbled upon the comments ...

Comment: What template do you need?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley In this video https://youtu.be/phjxbbLk4WM?t=59 it looks like the bash part in hidden behind `/**…*/` (however I couldn’t reproduce it). Also I just want to know why I do not see New ▸ Scala Script, although it is obviously there somewhere. You know, I want to understand that IDE. What really bugs me is that downvote and closevote. Do you really think a workaround must be good enough??

Comment: That might be an old version of IntelliJ; I don't see the "Scala Script" in my IntelliJ either (version 2019.3.3). I'd just create a new file or new Scala Class and delete whatever is in there to make it a blank `*.scala` file. The bit in `/**...*/` is just a comment of some sort, Scala files don't require a hashbang or anything like that at the start of the file to be runnable.

Comment: Also I'd recommend just using the Terminal/command line for scripting; IntelliJ changes pretty drastically between versions so unless you can find a tutorial with your version of IntelliJ it likely won't help you. Just writing `def greeting(): Unit = println("Hello world!") <NEW LINE>greeting()` in `hello.scala` and running it in the command line with `scala hello.scala` will print out `Hello world!`, without you having to go through an IDE to run it.

Comment: That being said, IntelliJ is fantastic for writing code - it's just normally easier to run Scala stuff through the command line than it is to try to get IntelliJ to behave itself.

Comment: The scripts I write are quite different. I do a lot of shell script stuff like testing the installed scala version and more before I tell scala to execute the rest of the file e.g. with `scala -J-Xmx2g -savecompiled -deprecation "$0" "$(readlink -f $0)" "$@"`. I already wrote some scripts with IntelliJ years ago. They still look fine on the newest version of IntelliJ. My scripts are huge, so I definitively need an IDE to help me writing the code.